# send form zend framework2 automatically

Tags: javascript, forms, time, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a poll after 20 minutes this should be sent or not completed. Intended to use javascript:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function send () {
         setTimeout ("document.forms [0] submit ().", 5000); 
    } 
    </ script> 
</ head> 
<body> 
    <form action="index2.html" method="get"> 
        <select name="sel" onchange="enviar()"> 
            <option> value="1"> 1 </ option> 
            <option> value="2"> 2 </ option> 
        </ select> 
        <input type="submit" /> 
     </form> 
 </ body> 
</ html>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of your `setTimeout` and also the code for submiting the form, are not correct. 
Please add an id and correct the syntax of your functions. Also be careful with the syntax of your tags.

Your code would be like this:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function send () {

        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("myForm").submit();},5000);
    } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <form action="index2.html" id="myForm" method="get"> 
        <select name="sel" onchange="enviar()"> 
            <option  value="1"> 1 </option> 
            <option  value="2"> 2 </option> 
         </select> 
        <input type="submit" /> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, You know how implement this solution en zf2 ?

Comment: You can build the form in the normal way, as you can see in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html
The javascript part, you can write it in the view, in the phtml file directly.